# Why onDestroy called when returning to parent activity in PAD?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Now there is a strange question, I have two Activity, A and B, the first to jump from A to B, B to input some properties, after completion, B return A, and call B.finish() method, but the problem is that when B finish, A method automatically calls the onDestroy and re onCreate, how is this going?

**This phenomenon occurs in the use of tablet PCs, and will not appear on the use of mobile phones.** PAD memory large enough. And set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

A and B Activity use same baseActivity with different viewGroup. so can't use `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

After B also tried to open C Activity, and then finish C, then B is normal onResume, did not execute onDestroy, why only in B returns A onDestroy A will lead it?

Life cycle is as follows:

```
A onCreate
A onStart
A onResume
------------------
A onPause
B onCreate
B onStart
B onResume
A onStop
-------------------call B.finish()
B onPause
A onDestroy
A onCreate
A onStart
A onResume
B onStop
B onDestroy
```

A onDestroy should not appear ah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the diagram in the following link. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html when you you call on finish() it will call on destroy after that call since you are done with the activity .

Comment: Thank you, I know, Call B.finish() it well destroy,but I can't call A.finish() but A is auto destroy in use PAD not in user Phone;

Comment: Hmm that is strange. The only two cases I can think of that it is happening is 1. if there is not enough memory (which you say is not a problem) and 2. something in the code is causing it to be killed. It is hard to tell without the code or the manifest if it is the second case